# Matlab - how to better structure arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab, data-structures, matlab-app-designer

I have points let's say around 50. Each point have x and y coordinates but not one but 50 - 200. What i want to do is to save it somehow to array or any other structure.

What i am doing now is simple.

STEP.1 - I found point in loop and save all x's and y's.

```
arrValX(end + 1) = app.gazeX(i);
arrValY(end + 1) = app.gazeY(i);
```

so i have two arrays 1x200 (for x) and 1x200 (for y)

STEP.2 I combine them into one

```
arrValCombine = [arrValX; arrValY];
```

now i have one array of 2x200

STEP.3 now I want to save this somehow structured so I can see this is point one this is point 2 ...
something like [point1,point2,point3,point4,....]
I am doing something like this

```
pointsArr = [pointsArr; arrValCombine]
```

Problem is that arrays are not always same size (2x200,2x120,2x66...) which gives me error and result is basically rows of data without knowing which one is point1 and which one is point2. (of course i know that first two rows are for point 1 next two rows for point 2 ...) but its not what i am looking for.

Can you please recommend me a way how to do it better (i mean step 3).

Comment: Regarding Step 1: If `app.gazeX` is a either a vector or a function that accepts a vector input, you might be able to forgo the loop altogether. If `app.gazeX` is a function that only accepts a scalar input, notice that using `arrValX(end+1)=...` can lead to unnecessary memory reallocations. Even though this may not be much of a problem at a total 200 iterations, it is usually better to initialize the vector to its full size (with `zeros(...)`, `nan(...)`, etc.) before entering the loop, and then address the specific entry you want to access (e.g. `for i=1:200, arrValX(i)=...`).

Comment: As for Step 3, you can use a cell array: `pointsArr=cell(...); for i=1:numel(pointsArr), pointsArr{i}=[arrValX; arrValY]; ...`. This enables different "points", as you call them, to have a different number of associated `(x,y)` pairs.

Comment: @Vicky Thanks those cell arrays looks exactly like what i need. :) will try it tomorrow.